# Differences between $('<div>')[0] and <div></div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm interacting with a third-party library which requires me to return a DOM element from a function:

```
option: function () {
    var option = $('<div>');
    return option[0];
}
```

Doing this causes the library to throw an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'replace'

However, doing this works just fine:

```
option: function () {
    return '<div>' + '</div>';
}
```

I thought these two expressions were identical, but apparently they are not. How can I use jQuery syntax, but express the result in such a way as to be the same type as the second statement?

For reference, here's the snippet of third-party code causing the issue:

```
// render markup
html = self.settings.render[templateName].apply(this, [data, escape_html]);

// add mandatory attributes
if (templateName === 'option' || templateName === 'option_create') {
    html = html.replace(regex_tag, '<$1 data-selectable');
}
```

Comment: Your first one is a DOM element, and your second one is a string.

Comment: Why do you have to use jQuery syntax? The second one clearly shows that it needs a string

Comment: The required return value is  not a DOM element as you suggest.

Comment: @KhanhTO I find it difficult to express more complex HTML structures in plain JavaScript and readability over efficiency is more important to me in this scenario.

Comment: If you're creating a complex structure, the jQuery function is going to require a string anyway, unless you're going to use a bunch of method calls, which usually gets far more complex.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/MeoMix/cddd1921fed5d3970c33 Is the javascript really preferred here? There's so much more room to introduce error..

Comment: @SeanAnderson: IMO, if you get rid of the unnecessary variables, then yes. But if you really want a clean syntax for creating new DOM structures, I'd suggest making a simple function that converts a structure like JSON to HTML.

Comment: can we see the third party library - love to take a look at the API to get a better idea

Comment: @Joe http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/ https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/src/selectize.js#L1800

Comment: if i am reading that API documentation right this selectize is a straight jQuery plugin.. meaning its "options" object is not required and the proper syntax to call it would be something like one of these `$('#theID').selectize();` /  `$('.theClass').selectize({create: false});` or even `$('#theID').selectize(someObjectVariable);`

Comment: It's a sub-option of the 'render' option. If you take a look at the examples on the first page you'll see he builds a lot of return statements with strings representing DOM elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need a string you could try something like this to create a new jquery element and return the string:

```
$('<div>')[0].outerHTML
```

or to reference an existing element by selector

```
$('.className')[0].outerHTML
$('#idName')[0].outerHTML
```

Comment: But why would one do that?

Comment: i interpret this as if he will possibly need to reference an existing element not always create one on the fly

Comment: @BlueSkies: I think the unspoken assumption is that `'<div></div>'` is just an example, the real version would be more complicated and the OP prefers to build the complicated HTML using jQuery.

Comment: @Joe: Oh, then you'll want to change the argument so that it isn't creating a new one.

Comment: understood just was giving an example based on his code - updated my code

Comment: `$('#idName')[0].outerHTML` would be problematic due to the inevitable duplicated `id` attribute that would result when the string went back into the DOM.

Comment: we could of course doctor the string to do whatever we wanted to it... however my next question would be what is this third party library and what precisely are we doing with it

Answer (score 2):

They are not even close to identical.  `'<div>' + '</div>'` (which is the same as just `'<div></div>'`, but presumably your real code is more complicated) is just a string.  Not an XML DOM object (node, element, anything).  Just a plain old garden-variety string.

Now, `'<div>'` is also a string, but when you pass it to jQuery's `$` function, what you get back is an object representing an actual `<div>` DOM element.  Totally not a string.